# Association model in simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Is there a way to put association model in `simple_form_for`?

I have a below code

```
= simple_form_for(@booth.chats, remote: true) do |f|
```

But this gives me below error:

```
NoMethodError at /booths/1
undefined method `model_name' for #<Class:0x86f6418>
```

Entire form code:

```
= simple_form_for(@booth, remote: true) do |f|
        = f.simple_fields_for(:chats) do |c| 
          .input-group
            %input#btn-input.form-control.input-sm{placeholder: "Type your message here...", type: "text"}
            %span.input-group-btn
              %button#btn-chat.btn.btn-warning.btn-sm{:type => 'submit'}
                Send
          = f.error_notification
```

Comment: Hi PD :D Show more of your code?

Comment: @Narfanator I just updated with entire form code :)

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your association model. From what I see in your code you are trying to access .chats which makes me think that this is a has_many / not has_one relationship.

I believe that if you are defining a has_one relationship then something very similar will work since there will be an active record reference to that model which is what simple_form_for requires.

Answer (score 0):

`@booth.chats` returns an `ActiveRecordRelation` and `simple_form_for` requires a `model` instance.  Association records are created using `simple_fields_for` within `simple_form_for` like follows:

```
= simple_form_for(@booth, remote: true) do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for(:chats) do |c| 
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. It works however I'm now getting duplicate input fields. Is this due to double loop?

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper, I do not see double loops.  Are you building `chats` twice in your controller's action?

Comment: booth has_many polymorphic chats. I'm trying to build a create new chat form inside booth show view